# How to stop refreshing of asp table content on any post back event

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have an `asp:grid` and a `asp:table` on a same `aspx page` field with same datasorce on page load. After loading of page any postback event table got refreshed and shows blank table but still grid view shows all records.

Can anyone tell me how can we prevent refreshing of `asp:table` on any postback event?

### Edit-1

### Code for `Grid` and `Table` fill

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = clsTransaction.Select(@"SELECT TOP 10000 A.reid AS [ID],
A.nm AS [Name],
B.nm AS [Server],
CASE WHEN D.nm IS NULL THEN A.nm ELSE D.nm END as [Parent],
CASE WHEN C.nm IS NULL THEN A.nm ELSE C.nm END as [Top Perent],
CASE WHEN A.isparent = 1 THEN 'Not a group reseller' ELSE 'Group reseller' END AS [Is Group] 
FROM tblReseller AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblwser B on (A.wsid = B.wsid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReseller AS C ON (A.tparentid = C.acid AND A.wsid = C.wsid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReseller AS D ON (A.parentid = D.acid AND A.wsid = D.wsid)", DataSendBSSWEB.ServerDbEnum.MainSqlServer, false);

        #region Table fill
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Text = dc.ColumnName;
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        }
        tblview.Rows.Add(tr);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            tr = new TableRow();
            foreach (object obj in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                tc = new TableCell();
                tc.Text = obj.ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            }
            tblview.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Grid Fill
        grvView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        grvView.DataBind();
        grvView.EnableViewState = true;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me where and how did you bind your datasource to your `Grid` and `table` ?

Comment: please check updated code in question.

Comment: What do you mean by *containtent* of a grid?

Comment: containtent of a grid means records of grid or table.

Comment: That would be the **content** of the grid .... (*containtent* does not exist as an English word...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asp:table object is not a data bound control and does not store its contents in ViewState . I think you should bind your table's data outside of 
    `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` :)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = clsTransaction.Select(@"SELECT TOP 10000 A.reid AS [ID],
A.nm AS [Name],
B.nm AS [Server],
CASE WHEN D.nm IS NULL THEN A.nm ELSE D.nm END as [Parent],
CASE WHEN C.nm IS NULL THEN A.nm ELSE C.nm END as [Top Perent],
CASE WHEN A.isparent = 1 THEN 'Not a group reseller' ELSE 'Group reseller' END AS [Is     Group] 
FROM tblReseller AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblwser B on (A.wsid = B.wsid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReseller AS C ON (A.tparentid = C.acid AND A.wsid = C.wsid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReseller AS D ON (A.parentid = D.acid AND A.wsid = D.wsid)",     DataSendBSSWEB.ServerDbEnum.MainSqlServer, false);

    #region Table fill
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        tc = new TableCell();
        tc.Text = dc.ColumnName;
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    }
    tblview.Rows.Add(tr);
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        tr = new TableRow();
        foreach (object obj in dr.ItemArray)
        {
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Text = obj.ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        }
        tblview.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
    #endregion


if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

    #region Grid Fill
    grvView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    grvView.DataBind();
    grvView.EnableViewState = true;
    #endregion
}
}
```

If you don't want to populate table on every pageLoad , I recommend `asp:FormView` .
You can see the reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227992%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
And you can add your table in FormView's `<ItemTemplate>` .

Comment: Yes i know that the `asp:table` is not a data bound control and does not store its contents in ViewState.But how could i do this in case of `asp:table`.

Comment: As I said Ashish , you should bind your table's data outside of `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` , see my coding :)

Comment: Yes i under stand that but i want to know that is there any way to do that without populate table on every page load.